# simple html code to show one large png (3060 x 2222px) center aligned - scroll vertically only

Tags: html

I would like to place one large png in the center of a web page to show my client. If have tried many codes, but it never aligns to the center.

The image is bigger than the browser. So left and right need to fall off.
The client is only allowed to scroll down, but not left or right.

Can anyone help me with the code, please? thx Seb

Comment: Where can I find the existing question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="your_image.jpg" style="display:block;margin:auto;width:100%;"/>
```

Comment: thanks, so no css what so ever? Sorry, my html knowledge is very basic.

Comment: the `style` attribute in the `image` tag is css, it is in-line css or in-line styling. Also, I just saw your point of only vertical scroll and edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, but the 100% width makes the images the same size as the browser. I want it to disappear left and right.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you would like to use a Background Image. If you would like to do this, you could try the following code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

You could just set that in the CSS, and you would then have a fixed background image! Now, if you just want a image centered (sorry, I thought you might want the above), you could try the following code:

```css
img {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
```

With the first block of code being in the CSS file, and the second piece of code being in the HTML file.

Comment: Thanks Michael, can I combine both codes in one file or do they need to be in two separate files? I would like to show the middle of the png to my client, so left and right need to fall of screen, depending how big the screen is, the client gets to see more.

Comment: <blink>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>

    img {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
    }

    </style>
    </head>

     <body>

     <img src="image.png">

    </body>
    </html>
    </blink>